# Pass login name as a variable in a SQL Server script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have the following script that I want the production guys to execute using sqlcmd. I want to pass the name of the APP_POOL_USER as a variable to the script, since they want it that way. Don't ask me why.

```
CREATE USER [$(APP_POOL_USER)] FOR LOGIN [$(APP_POOL_USER)] 
  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[schema]
```

I get the following error when I execute the code above

> Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>       '$(APP_POOL_USER)' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.

How can this be done?

EDIT:

This is the batch file to execute it I have so far

```
@ECHO OFF

SET DB_SERVER_NAME = ".\SQLEXPRESS"
SET APP_POOL_ACCOUNT = "ExUserAccout"




sqlcmd.exe -E -S "%DB_SERVER_NAME%" -i "SQL_DB.sql" -o SQL_DB.log -v APP_POOL_USER="%APP_POOL_ACCOUNT%"
```

Comment: Can't you build the "`CREATE USER...`" command first (using the variable), then pass that as a query argument to sqlcmd?

Comment: I guess. This is part of a big script I got out of SQL Management Studio. I'm more of a Front-End guy. Can I do that in the same script?

Comment: The batch file you have above, it must return a different error now? Oh I see, you're passing in a .sql file, not a query. Well we'd have to see what's in `SQL_DB.sql`, I guess.

Comment: The 'SQL_DB.sql' file the sql to recreate the DB I have in development. It starts with he creation of users and roles, which is the part I paste in the question.

Comment: sqlcmd.exe can't magically replace all your tokens with values. You must do that either by manipulating the .sql file first or by extracting its contents, manipulating them, and then passing them as a command instead of passing them as a file. Maybe you should ask them why they want it that way - their reason(s) may help us think of other valid workarounds.

Comment: Also have "they" heard of PowerShell?

Comment: Ok. So, it looks that what I'm trying to do is not possible using sqlcmd. They told me that they did not want anything hard coded in the scripts. It looks that this part will have to be, right?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "hard-coded" ... someone is going to have to type the user account name at some point. You can certainly do all kinds of things with a batch script that ultimately calls sqlcmd.exe, but you're going to be either limited or writing cumbersome code (hence the suggestion re: PowerShell).

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should be happy to work for somebody that actually knows what is doing. Using sqlcmd script variables and setting them from environment variables or from script arguments is a very good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET DB_SERVER_NAME=.\SQLEXPRESS
SET APP_POOL_ACCOUNT=ExUserAccout
```

Don't leave spaces between the equal sign and the variable name and value.